# MySQL Select Return a certain percentage of a Column (Binary Values)

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL User table with a column for Gender - 1 Male & 0 Female. Each Users has a Gender.

I want to be able to return a percentage of male/female when I say return 100 Users. EG: 40 Accounts Male and 60 Accounts Female - 40/60 Split.

How can I do this with MySQL?

```
select * from users where gender?
```

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically want to get 40 males and 60 females, then use `union all`:

```
(select u.*
 from users u
 where u.gender = 'male'
 limit 40
) union all
(select u.*
 from users u
 where u.gender = 'female'
 limit 40
);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ma.gender
     , COUNT(1) AS total
     , COUNT(1) / t.gender * 100 AS `percentage`
  FROM users ma
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS gender FROM users) t
 GROUP
    BY ma.gender
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 100*SUM(u.gender)/SUM(1) AS pc
FROM users as u
WHERE ...
```

`pc` is then the % of Male (since 1 = Male, 0 = Female)